# Azure cosmosdb replaceCollection returns MethodNotAllowed

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using [Azure Cosmos DB Node.js SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-node) to replace collection as follows

```
client.replaceCollection(databaseLink, collectionDef, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    console.log(`Collection '${collectionId}' updated`)
  }
})
```

However, I'm getting the following error

```
{ 
  code: 405,
  body: '{"code":"MethodNotAllowed","message":"RequestHandler.Put"}'
}
```

I also want to point out that `client.createCollection` works as expected. I'm thinking it might be a permission issue but I couldn't find anything pertaining to changing allowed methods in the [api documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/DocumentClient.html) nor in the Azure Portal. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share what your `databaseLink` looks like? My guess is that you're using a link to the database instead of a collection for replacement (i.e. effectively telling service to update the database) and getting this error because updating database is not allowed.

Comment: @GauravMantri That is exactly it! Thanks! Write that in the answer section and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the reason you're getting this error is because you're providing `database link` instead of `collection link` which essentially is telling the service to update the database instead of collection. Since updating database is not allowed in Cosmos DB, you are getting this `MethodNotAllowed` error.